# magento create product attribute to upload images via installer script

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to use installer script for creating product attribute of image type.

I want to use the image type attribute so that the admin can upoad the images and we can fetch it on the front end.

I used the below code for the same

```
$data9= array (
            'attribute_set' =>  'Product Bundler Package',
            'group' => 'Bundled Package Data',
            'label'    => 'Preset1 thumbnail',
            'visible'     => true,
            'type'    => 'varchar',
            'input'   => 'file',
            'system'   => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => 1, //defaults to false; if true, define a group
        );
        $installer->addAttribute('catalog_product','bundle_preset1_thumb',$data9);
```

The image attributes are created but i am not able to upload the images with this.
Can anyone tell me why i am not able to do so how can i create image uploader product attribute.